# how to check the event handlers' properties in js?

Tags: javascript

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<body>
<style type="text/css">
#a {background-color:blue;width:100px;height:200px;}
#b {background-color:red;margin-left:25px;width:50px;height:100px;}
</style> 
<div id="a">a
    <div id="b">b</div> 
</div>
<script>
document.getElementById("a").onclick = function() {console.log("A is clicked");} 
document.getElementById("b").onclick = function() {console.log("B is clicked");} 
document.onclick = function() {console.log("Document is clicked");} 
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Question:

For above codes, it registered 3 click events handlers, they are also objects, right? if so, how could I check these 3 handlers/objects' properties, methods in console?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do/find out? The event handlers are just functions in this case. They have the same properties as any other function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do

```
document.getElementById("a").onclick = function() {console.log("A is clicked");}
```

you are just assigning a function to that anchors `onclick` property, then when that anchor is clicked, the browser will fire that function. If you want to read what this function is, you just need to output

```
console.log(document.getElementById("a").onclick);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm really not sure what you are trying to do, maybe this helps you:

```
document.getElementById("a").onclick = function(event) {
    console.log("A is clicked");
    console.log(this); //refers to the source element object
    console.log(event); //refers to the event object
}
```